# insert random strings from a list using sql

Tags: sql, oracle

i've created a table like this : region(id, name) and i want to insert into this table some rows , the name should be choosed randomly from a list like ['east', 'west'], how can i do that ?

Comment: Which database engine are you using? SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, etc.?

Comment: do you have any more information on your requirements?  What have you tried?  is this mysql/sqlserver/...

Comment: i'm using Oracle ...i can use python or php but i'm limitted to use Oracle

Answer (score 0):

Insert 10 random rows with...

Oracle:

```
INSERT INTO region(name)
SELECT rndm.name 
  FROM (SELECT 1 n
          FROM dual
       CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 365
     ) gen
 CROSS 
  JOIN (SELECT 'west' name FROM dual
         UNION ALL
        SELECT 'east' FROM dual
         UNION ALL
        SELECT 'north' FROM dual
     ) rndm
 WHERE rownum <= 10
 ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE
```

SQL Server:

```
INSERT INTO region (name)
SELECT TOP 10 rndm.name
  FROM sys.all_objects a1
 CROSS
  JOIN (VALUES ('east'),
               ('west')) rndm(name)
 ORDER BY CHECKSUM(NEWID())
```

MySQL:

```
INSERT INTO region (name)
SELECT rndm.name
  FROM information_schema.columns v
 CROSS
  JOIN (SELECT 'east' as name UNION ALL
        SELECT 'west') rndm
 ORDER BY RAND()
 LIMIT 10
```

Postgres:

```
 INSERT INTO region(NAME)
 SELECT unnest(ARRAY['west','east'])
   FROM generate_series(1, 100)
  ORDER BY random()
  LIMIT 10
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but i thin you diden't understand my problem, in fact the table is empty is like that Region(id, name) i'm using a loop to insert id but for the name i want him to be randomly inserted from a list

Comment: That's exactly what it does though. Each of those statements will indeert 10 rows with a random name from the list in the query, you can change the number too. You don't need a loop for anything here, especially if you're using a sequence for id. Or you can post your code and tell where you want your random values, because it's hard to guess.

Comment: The Oracle solution - which is the only one I've tested, as it turns out that's the only one the OP actually wanted - is not random. The inserted values are in order: *west, east, north, west, east, north, west, east, north, west*.

Comment: [I tested using dbfiddle and looks random to me](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=6d781f1ead49495c5d2ce6b7d6db735a), order also changes every time I run it.

Answer (score 0):

This is an Oracle solution. The first subquery generates ten random integers between 1 and 3, using Oracle's CONNECT BY syntax. The second subquery associates the region name with a number between 1 and 3. These are joined in the main query to populate the table:

```
insert into region (id, name)
with rnd as (
     select level as lvl, round(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(0.5,3.4999999999), 0) as rnd
     from dual
     connect by level <= 10
 ) , regn as (  
    select 1 as rno, 'west' as rname from dual union all
    select 2 as rno, 'east' as rname from dual union all
    select 3 as rno, 'north' as rname from dual
)
select rnd.lvl
       , regn.rname
from rnd
     join regn on rnd.rnd = regn.rno
/
```